# How to get a number from a text field?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How I can scan a number from a text field?

For example, in C

```
int x,area;
scanf("%d",&x);
area=r*r*3.14;
printf(" the area is %d",area);
```

How to do this on iPhone in Objective-C with a text field?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It performs a similar function to scanf, but works on NSString objects.

Answer (score 2):

if it's in a textfield, you can do

```
double r=[textFieldName.text doubleValue];
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"the area is %f",r*r*3.14];
someLabelYouAreUsingToDisplayResults.text=result;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote works perfectly fine in Objective-C (or rather would, if it wasn't buggy).  **Everything that works in C works in Objective-C, without modification**.

That said, there are more idiomatic ways to do such things in the Objective-C language (and Cocoa libraries), which I'm sure others will point out to you.  See **Robot Woods**'s answer for an idiomatic example of how to read from a text field, for instance.